# Check if my laptop can support SATA 3.0g/s

Tags: hard-drive

I want to upgrade my harddrive on my laptop. I'm not sure if it's SATA I or SATA II and I'm wondering how can I check if it's SATA II compatible. I am using a HP dv6500t

Comment: As much as it is nice to know, It should not really change your choice on the hard drive to get, as it should be backward compatible.

Comment: I was under the impression that the OP was asking if his laptop supported SATA II and not the hard drive: " I'm wondering how can I check if **it's** SATA II compatible." The crucial word being "it's" -- is "it" the hard drive or is "it" the laptop. Hmmm...

Comment: Check your chipset model(i.e. PM45) and google it for specifications. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Software Information for Windows](http://www.gtopala.com/siw-download.html) (aka SIW), you can see what type of drive your computer currently has. I would download the "stand-alone" version, as that doesn't require you to install anything.

You can see below that for my laptop, I have a [120GB Western Digital WD1200BEVS](http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?item=N82E16822136072), which is a SATA I (1.5 Gb/s) drive.

[image: siw screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to answer any question about a PC's capabilities is to check the vendor's website (In your case, HP.com), search for your model and then inspect the specifications that are listed.

For example:

1. Go to Hp.com
2. Click "Support and Drivers"
3. Select the "See support and troubleshooting information" radio button
4. Put your laptop's model number in the "Enter Product Name / Number" field

From there, you have heaps of information, FAQs and other literature that is specifically related to your laptop.

In addition, [follow these instructions](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01961011&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=3369405) to find the specific product specification sheet for your HP laptop.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a new harddrive - apart from being "good to know" - it shouldn't really matter if your computer supports SATA II or not as it was designed to be backwards compatible.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA_II#SATA_Revision_2.0_.28SATA_3Gb.2Fs.29